# Struggling to register event handler for System.IO.Ports.SerialPort SerialDataReceivedEventHandler

Tags: c#, .net-core, event-handling, serial-port

I'm having a weird issue. I'm trying to write code to read from the SerialPort in a .Net Core console app. I am using Microsoft's System.IO.Ports v4.7.0 library from NuGet. I copied the code from here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

However, when I paste the code into Visual Studio, I immediately get this error:

**Error CS0123: No overload for 'DataReceivedHandler' matches delegate 'SerialDataReceivedEventHandler'**

My code is very simple:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

public class SerialComms
{
    SerialPort _serialPort;

    private void SetupSerialPort()
    {
        _serialPort.PortName = "/dev/ttyS0";
        _serialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
        _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
        _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        _serialPort.Open();
    }

    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        Console.Write(indata);
    }
}
```

I've spent hours on this and cannot for the life of me figure out where I'm going wrong. The event handler's signature is correct as far as I can tell. Any ideas?

Comment: I just pasted the code in visual studio but did not receive the error you are stating.

Comment: What .net core and System.IO.Ports version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dash. I am using . Net Core 3.1 and System.IO.Ports v4.7.0. I am developing in Visual Studio 2019 Community, on latest version of Windows 10.

Comment: I will try restarting my pc...

Comment: If that doesn't fix the issue, try to delete the .vs folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but replacing:

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

with

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Fixed the issue.